# XIB files have wrong formatting when app runs on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xib

So in my XIB files, I have labels and buttons that are formatted. But when I run the app on my iPhone, the labels and buttons are not spaced correctly, and the view does not look like the XIB file. Can someone help me out?

Comment: are you using autolayout functionality ?

Comment: check your target in simulator and the device you are checking in. And check for AutoLayout.

Comment: I was using aytolayout. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `xib property screen->Show File Inspector->uncheck Use Autolayout`

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

select the xib file and uncheck the`AutoLayout` option if you don't target for iOS6.
 try